# Disable button when dropdown is empty

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a problem I can't find a solution.

I need the submit button to disable when there is no a valid dropdown option selected.

At the start it works very well. If the second dropdown Is set to "Provincia" the submit button is disabled. As soon as I change the first dropdown and the value of the second changes automatically the button is still disabled, but as soon as I edit a text input I enables because it updates with keyup function.

First:
[image: First step]

Second:
[image: Second step]

The main problem comes when is set the first dropdown to the default value "Regione". The second dropdown becomes empty and not the default value "Provincia". This is for me ok, but the button doesn't become disabled, even if I update a text input.

I would like to make the button disable/enable as soon as the dropdown is changed trying to maintain this code.

Third:
[image: Third step]

The dropdown in the code is [name="nascita_provincia"], other are text inputs.

I have other dropdown, but once will find a solution to one will implement it to all of them. Would like also to avoid changing the html/php code.

My jQuery code is this:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    validate();
    $('input[name="first_name"], input[name="last_name"], input[name="nascita_citta"], input[name="residenza_citta"], input[name="residenza_indirizzo"], input[name="domicilio_citta"], input[name="domicilio_indirizzo"], input[name="cellulare"], input[name="phone"], input[name="occupazione"], input[name="cfiscale"], input[name="banca_iban"], input[name="banca_istituto"], input[name="banca_intestatario"], input[name="banca_abi"], input[name="banca_cab"], input[name="banca_cin"], input[name="banca_agenzia"], input[name="banca_cc"], [name="nascita_provincia"]').change(validate);
    $('input[name="first_name"], input[name="last_name"], input[name="nascita_citta"], input[name="residenza_citta"], input[name="residenza_indirizzo"], input[name="domicilio_citta"], input[name="domicilio_indirizzo"], input[name="cellulare"], input[name="phone"], input[name="occupazione"], input[name="cfiscale"], input[name="banca_iban"], input[name="banca_istituto"], input[name="banca_intestatario"], input[name="banca_abi"], input[name="banca_cab"], input[name="banca_cin"], input[name="banca_agenzia"], input[name="banca_cc"]').keyup(function() {validate();});
});

function validate(){
    if ($('input[name="first_name"]').val().length   >   0   &&
        $('input[name="last_name"]').val().length  >   0   &&
        $('input[name="nascita_citta"]').val().length  >   0   &&
        $('input[name="residenza_citta"]').val().length  >   0   &&
        $('input[name="residenza_indirizzo"]').val().length  >   0   &&
        $('input[name="domicilio_citta"]').val().length  >   0   &&
        $('input[name="domicilio_indirizzo"]').val().length  >   0   &&
        $('input[name="cellulare"]').val().length  >   0   &&
        $('input[name="phone"]').val().length  >   0   &&
        $('input[name="occupazione"]').val().length  >   0   &&
        $('input[name="cfiscale"]').val().length  >   0   &&
        $('input[name="banca_iban"]').val().length  >   0   &&
        $('input[name="banca_istituto"]').val().length  >   0   &&
        $('input[name="banca_intestatario"]').val().length  >   0   &&
        $('input[name="banca_abi"]').val().length  >   0   &&
        $('input[name="banca_cab"]').val().length  >   0   &&
        $('input[name="banca_cin"]').val().length  >   0   &&
        $('input[name="banca_agenzia"]').val().length  >   0   &&
        $('input[name="banca_cc"]').val().length  >   0   &&
        $('[name="nascita_provincia"]').val()  !=   0   &&
        $('[name="nascita_provincia"]').val() != 'Provincia'
    ) {
        jQuery("#update_details").prop('disabled', false);
    }
    else {
        jQuery("#update_details").prop('disabled', true);
    }
}
```

Here is also the html code of the interested field:

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>
                        <?= trans('luogo_nascita'); ?>
                    </label>
                  <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <select id="birthday_sel" name="nascita_regione" class="form-control" onchange="configureDropDownLists1(this,document.getElementById('county_birth'))">
                            <?php
                                $birth_region = "";
                                if ($currentUser->nascita_regione == "") {
                                    $birth_region = trans('region');
                                } else {
                                    $birth_region = ($currentUser->nascita_regione);
                                }
                            ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo($birth_region); ?>" selected><?php echo($birth_region); ?></option>
                            <option disabled="true">--------</option>
                            <option value="Abruzzo">Abruzzo</option>
                            <option value="Basilicata">Basilicata</option>
                            <option value="Calabria">Calabria</option>
                            <option value="Campania">Campania</option>
                            <option value="Emilia-Romagna">Emilia-Romagna</option>
                            <option value="Friuli-Venezia Giulia">Friuli-Venezia Giulia</option>
                            <option value="Lazio">Lazio</option>
                            <option value="Liguria">Liguria</option>
                            <option value="Lombardia">Lombardia</option>
                            <option value="Marche">Marche</option>
                            <option value="Molise">Molise</option>
                            <option value="Piemonte">Piemonte</option>
                            <option value="Puglia">Puglia</option>
                            <option value="Sardegna">Sardegna</option>
                            <option value="Sicilia">Sicilia</option>
                            <option value="Trentino-Alto Adige/Südtirol">Trentino-Alto Adige/Südtirol</option>
                            <option value="Toscana">Toscana</option>
                            <option value="Umbria">Umbria</option>
                            <option value="Valle d'Aosta/Vallée d'Aoste">Valle d'Aosta/Vallée d'Aoste</option>
                            <option value="Veneto">Veneto</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <select id="county_birth" name="nascita_provincia" class="form-control">
                            <?php
                                $birth_county = "";
                                if ($currentUser->nascita_provincia == "") {
                                    $birth_county = trans('county');
                                } else {
                                    $birth_county = ($currentUser->nascita_provincia);
                                }
                            ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo($birth_county); ?>" selected><?php echo($birth_county); ?></option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                      <input type="text" name="nascita_citta" class="form-control" value="<?= e($currentUser->nascita_citta); ?>" placeholder="<?= trans('city'); ?>">
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
```

The second dropdown populates depending on the choise of the first dropdown. There is a separate js file for doing this.

Comment: you should post your html code also here.

Comment: Please Cristian create a complete snippet with tools `<>`

Comment: You should refactor that code so that you not repeat yourself.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini posted the code, but the problem is that I'm using some js files and some php in the code, so I can't make a snippet.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra posted the code above